# How can I import a source file from my library into build.rs?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, build-script

I have the following file structure:

```
src/
    lib.rs
    foo.rs
build.rs
```

I would like to import something from `foo.rs` (`lib.rs` has `pub mod foo` in it already) into `build.rs`. (I'm trying to import a type in order to generate some JSON schema at build time)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot cleanly — the build script is used to *build* the library, so by definition must run before the library is built.

## Clean solution

Put the type into another library and import the new library into both the build script and your original library

```
.
├── the_library
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   ├── build.rs
│   └── src
│       └── lib.rs
└── the_type
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src
        └── lib.rs
```

**the_type/src/lib.rs**

```rust
pub struct TheCoolType;
```

**the_library/Cargo.toml**

```
# ...

[dependencies]
the_type = { path = "../the_type" }

[build-dependencies]
the_type = { path = "../the_type" }
```

**the_library/build.rs**

```rust
fn main() {
    the_type::TheCoolType;
}
```

**the_library/src/lib.rs**

```rust
pub fn thing() {
    the_type::TheCoolType;
}
```

## Hacky solution

Use something like [`#[path] mod ...`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html#the-path-attribute) or [`include!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include.html) to include the code twice. This is basically pure textual substitution, so it's very brittle.

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
├── build.rs
└── src
    ├── foo.rs
    └── lib.rs
```

**build.rs**

```rust
// One **exactly one** of this...
#[path = "src/foo.rs"]
mod foo;

// ... or this
// mod foo {
//     include!("src/foo.rs");
// }

fn main() {
    foo::TheCoolType;
}
```

**src/lib.rs**

```rust
mod foo;

pub fn thing() {
    foo::TheCoolType;
}
```

**src/foo.rs**

```rust
pub struct TheCoolType;
```

Comment: Isn't there an even hackier solution of just [`include!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include.html)-ing the module into the build script?

Comment: @Masklinn isn't that what I describe in the section titled "Hacky solution": *Use something like `include!` or `#[path] mod ...`*?

Comment: yep, I focused on the snippets and managed to overlook both the text and the comment mentioning include...

Comment: @Masklinn the code example [was only added in the most recent revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67905413/revisions), but I mentioned the possibility of `include` from the first post ;-)